# Converting standalone code into a function

Tags: python, function, anaconda, spyder

Disclaimer: picked up coding a few months ago, more often than not I tend to use incorrect language, apologies in advance.

I am writing a function that would convert an sbml model(.xml file) into something more readable in latex(converting to .tex files).

I have run into a problem while transferring the standalone code into a function. My best guess is that the problem is in a nested function (after transferring) `listfiller`.

My main (and not too beautiful) way of getting information from the sbml model is prewriting the code into a list (called `Commands` in the function, those are basically calls to functions in a libSBML library that extract some kisnd of information [strings, integers ,etc] ) that `listfiller` evaluates based on whatever object (called `obj`) I feed into the nested function.

For some reason, once I move the entire code into a function, the `listfiller` does not see the objects anymore. Moreover, it does see the ones that are literally named `obj`:

Tried to put `*args` and `**kwargs` instead of `obj` to no avail

Naming everything 'obj' would be impossible (i.e. really cumbersome)

Here's the function itself (need [tellurium library](http://tellurium.analogmachine.org/) to run: `pip install tellurium`) and any .xml file for libSBML like [this](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/model/download/BIOMD0000000221.2?filename=BIOMD0000000221_url.xml)

```
def xml2tex(name):
    import tesbml

    def listfiller(Commands , obj,  tofill = [], twoD = 1):
            '''
            Uses a dismal method of evaluating a piece of code 
            from 'Commands' to fit a specific string into 'tofill' 
            takes in a libsbml object as obj

            if twoD = 0, then does not fill 'tofill' with the templin as one element
            but returns the compiled templin as 1-D list
            '''
            l = len(Commands)
            templin = [None]*l
            for i in range(l):
                templin[i] = eval(Commands[i])
            if twoD == 1:
                tofill.append(templin)
                return tofill
            elif twoD == 0:
                return templin


    reader = tesbml.SBMLReader()
    mod = reader.readSBML(name)
    Reactions = []
    l = mod.model.getNumReactions()
    Rlist = ['R.getId()','R.getReversible()','R.getFast()']
    for x in range(0,l):
        R = mod.model.getReaction(x)
        RL = listfiller(Rlist, R, twoD=0) #starting the element of common matrix/list to append at the end

        Reactions.append(RL);
    return Reactions
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-56-48f48283afb5>", line 1, in <module>
    xml2tex('model.xml')

  File "/Users/sergejczan/Desktop/Lab/untitled1.py", line 38, in xml2tex
    RL = listfiller(Rlist, obj = R, twoD=0) #starting the element of common matrix/list to append at the end

  File "/Users/sergejczan/Desktop/Lab/untitled1.py", line 23, in listfiller
    templin[i] = eval(Commands[i])

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'R' is not defined
```

Comment: The code that you have shown does not involve a variable `something` (other than in an obscure parenthetical) so your error message lacks adequate context. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Btw, [don't set empty list as default value for argument](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions). Also there's no reason to predefine list length, you can use [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions). And `tofill.append(templin)` will append whole list, not it's elements (not quite sure is it what you need).

Comment: Modified to be reproducible the best I could.

Comment: Got it, put the full error message now

Comment: The only code that you posted is a function definition. Function definitions by themselves do not trigger run-time errors. Runtime errors (if any) occur when the functions are *called*. Your code does not invoke the function it defines. The traceback that you show seems to refer to code that you haven't actually posted.